# Can you apply animations from Javascript to Java-FX Objects using Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, animation, javafx, nashorn

I have a `Text` object in JavaFX, that acts as a Title for a Scene.

Can i call animation effects (`fadeIn`, `fadeOut`) on said FX object or create Animation Queues in JS and then apply that to my FX objects, using Nashorn, and have the effects display accordingly in the Scene?

**Examples**

- Making the Text object "pulsate" based on a timed cycle. (Custom Animation created in JS)
- Slowly unfolding the text element with `slideDown` function from JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply animate (`fadeIn, fadeOut, slideDown, pulsate`, etc) any node using [javafx.animation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) without wrapping `javascript` program in `Nashron`.

**FadeIn**

```
private void fadeIn(Node node) {
    FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(
            Duration.millis(900), 
            node
    );
    fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
    fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
    fadeTransition.play();
}
```

**FadeOut**

```
private void fadeOut(Node node) {
    FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(
            Duration.millis(900), 
            node
    );
    fadeTransition.setFromValue(1);
    fadeTransition.setToValue(0);
    fadeTransition.play();
}
```

**Slide-down**

```
private void slideDown(Node node) {
    TranslateTransition slideDown = new TranslateTransition(
            Duration.millis(900), 
            node
    );
    slideDown.setFromY(-400);
    slideDown.setToY(0);
    slideDown.play();
}
```

**Pulsate**

```
private void pulsate(Node node) {

    node.setEffect(new DisplacementMap());

    ScaleTransition scaleUp = new ScaleTransition(
            Duration.millis(400), node
    );
    scaleUp.setFromX(1);
    scaleUp.setFromY(1);
    scaleUp.setToX(1.4);
    scaleUp.setToY(1.4);
    scaleUp.play();

    scaleUp.setOnFinished(su -> {
        ScaleTransition scaleDown = new ScaleTransition(
                Duration.millis(400), node
        );
        scaleDown.setFromX(1.4);
        scaleDown.setFromY(1.4);
        scaleDown.setToX(1);
        scaleDown.setToY(1);
        scaleDown.play();
        scaleDown.setOnFinished(sd -> node.setEffect(null));
    });
}
```

A simple demo for `Text` using those animations,

```
public class TextAnimationDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getContent(), 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private BorderPane getContent() {
        Text text = new Text("Title");

        Button fadeIn = new Button("Fade In");
        fadeIn.setOnAction(e -> fadeIn(text));

        Button fadeOut = new Button("Fade Out");
        fadeOut.setOnAction(e -> fadeOut(text));

        Button slideDown = new Button("Slide-Down");
        slideDown.setOnAction(event -> slideDown(text));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(text);
        root.setRight(fadeOut);
        root.setLeft(fadeIn);
        root.setBottom(slideDown);
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Javafx animations from Nashorn. I ported the above Java code by Shekkar Raee to nashorn. You can run the following script using nashorn jjs shell tool.

```
// Usage: jjs -fx textanimation.js

// JavaFX classes used
var BorderPane = Java.type("javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane")
var Button = Java.type("javafx.scene.control.Button")
var Duration = Java.type("javafx.util.Duration")
var FadeTransitionBuilder = Java.type("javafx.animation.FadeTransitionBuilder")
var Scene = Java.type("javafx.scene.Scene")
var Text = Java.type("javafx.scene.text.Text")
var TranslateTransitionBuilder = Java.type("javafx.animation.TranslateTransitionBuilder")

function start(stage) {
    //target node
    var text = new Text("Title")

    //fade-in animation
    var fadeIn = new Button("Fade In")
    fadeIn.onAction = function(e) {
         var fade1 = FadeTransitionBuilder
                .create()
                .node(text)
                .duration(Duration.millis(900))
                .fromValue(0)
                .toValue(1)
                .build()
         fade1.play()
    }

    //fade-out animation
    var fadeOut = new Button("Fade Out")
    fadeOut.onAction = function(e) {
         var fade2 = FadeTransitionBuilder
                .create()
                .node(text)
                .duration(Duration.millis(900))
                .fromValue(1)
                .toValue(0)
                .build()
         fade2.play()
    }

    //slide-down animation
    var slideDown = new Button("Slide-Down")
    slideDown.onAction = function(event) {
         var slide = TranslateTransitionBuilder.create()
                .node(text).duration(Duration.millis(900))
                .fromY(-400)
                .toY(0)
                .build()
         slide.play()
    }

    var root = new BorderPane()
    root.setCenter(text)
    root.setRight(fadeOut)
    root.setLeft(fadeIn)
    root.setBottom(slideDown)

    var scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250)

    stage.title = "Animation Demo"
    stage.scene = scene
    stage.show()
}
```

Comment: Note that

    root.setCenter(text)
    root.setRight(fadeOut)
    root.setLeft(fadeIn)
    root.setBottom(slideDown)
    
can be expressed as 

    root.center = text
    root.right = fadeOut
    root.left = fadeIn
    root.bottom = slideDown